# Users in hawt.io in an standalone java app

Tags: hawtio

I would like to know how can I have users for hawt.io when using it in an standalone java app. I believe that you need to define a realm like containers do, but is there any guide or easy way to do this? I just want to protect my hawt.io instance with user and password.

Comment: Why have your tagged this question with Apache Karaf?

Comment: Maybe somebody who is using hawt.io with Karaf knows how to do with  standalone. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jetty or Tomcat as the embedded web server to run hawtio standalone. Then you can use their security out of the box. And its just like securing any other WAR web application, eg setup their realm, and setup web.xml stuff.

For example this is done in the Apache ActiveMQ distribution which has an embedded Jetty server for the web consoles and WebSocket support.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am taking a look to it.